# Python - Binary Text Replacer

Tags: python, string

So I am working on something and I need to replace substrings with spaces, and get every different combination of that substring with the spaces, I want to do this using binary as a comparison.
So e.g.

```
0 0 0 = A B C
0 0 1 = A B _
0 1 0 = A _ C
0 1 1 = A _ _
1 0 0 = _ B C
1 0 1 = _ B _
1 1 1 = _ _ _  (put in code formatting to keep shape)
```

I am using python and have this so far, but it just output's an empty array.
Please could somebody help? :)

```
string ="abcde"

binary5=["0"]
final=[]

for count in range(0,32):
    counter=0

    count =bin(count)
    count=str(count)
    count = count.lstrip('-0b')
    for i in range(len(count)):
        if count[i] == "1":
            counter=counter+1
    if counter<6:
        binary5.append(count)

    print(binary5)

for i in range(0,32):
    bintest = str(binary5[i])
    bintest.split()
    string2=string
    for x in range(0,len(string)):
        try:
            if bintest[x] == "1":
                string2.split()
                string2.pop[x]
                string2.insert(x-1," ")
                string2.join()
                print(string2)
                final.append(string2)
        except:
            pass

print(final)
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. I understand the example at the top, but I have no idea what the code has to do with that.

Comment: Are you interested in an entire replacement? Including 2 blank lines and a final `print`, I have 8 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have a methodology problem: you *specifically* throw away your diagnostic information.  Therefore, when you have a problem, you have no idea what you did wrong: you ignored the error message.

The `try-except` block has no relation to your algorithm.  Get rid of it, and start debugging your code.  The first error is

```
            string2.pop[x]
```

There is no `pop` method for type `string`.  Next, you keep `split`ting strings that have no spaces or punctuation; I'm not sure what you think this is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code is doing. It's way too complicated. Here's a direct replacement.

```
import string
from itertools import product

def translate_tuple(tup):
    ''' Takes a tuple of any length containing 0s or 1s.
        Returns a new tuple with the correct letters. '''
    return tuple(l if tup[i] == 0 else '_' for i, l in enumerate(string.ascii_letters[:len(tup)]))

def get_pairs(length):
    ''' Get all pairs of binary and translated text. '''
    for binary_tup in product((0, 1,), repeat=length):
        yield ' '.join(map(str, binary_tup)), ' '.join(translate_tuple(binary_tup))

for b, t in get_pairs(3):
    print(f'{b} = {t}')
```

Which prints:

```
0 0 0 = a b c
0 0 1 = a b _
0 1 0 = a _ c
0 1 1 = a _ _
1 0 0 = _ b c
1 0 1 = _ b _
1 1 0 = _ _ c
1 1 1 = _ _ _
```

You can use arbitrary sized binary numbers by providing a different length to `get_pairs()`

```
In [36]: for i in range(10):
    ...:     b, t = next(g)
    ...:     print(f'{b} = {t}')
    ...:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s _
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r _ t
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r _ _
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q _ s t
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q _ s _
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q _ _ t
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q _ _ _
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p _ r s t
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 = a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p _ r s _
```

---

#### Explanation

The most important bit is `translate_tuple()`, but you can use `itertools.product` to get all the input tuples.

`translate_tuple(tup)` expects a binary tuple of any length, e.g:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

And returns a new tuple in the format you described:

```
(0, 0, 0)          => ('a', 'b', 'c')
(0, 1, 0)          => ('a', '_', 'c')
(1, 1, 1, 1)       => ('_', '_', '_', '_')
(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)    => ('a', '_', 'c', '_', 'e')
```

The next function `get_pairs()` just generates all the binary tuples of a given length, and then yields the string of the binary tuple and the string of the result joined by spaces.

Then you can print out the strings. It would probably be better to yield the raw tuples, and create the strings immediately before printing, but I wanted to keep it mostly in that function.